# Fancybox 1.3.4 just wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

Hey im trying to implement fancybox 1.3.4 and I just cant get it to work
Heres my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery    /1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

/* This is basic - uses default settings */

$(".image").fancybox();

/* Using custom settings */

$(".iframe").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': false
});


$("a[href$=.jpg],a[href$=.png],a[href$=.gif]").fancybox();

$(".youtube").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding': 0,
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'title': this.title,
        'width': 680,
        'height': 495,
        'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type': 'swf',
        'swf': {
            'wmode': 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen': 'true'
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This is the image  I want fancybox to open. Presently it just shows up in a new tab.
I use firebug and I can see that every script and stylesheet loads.

```
 <a class="image" href="http://localhost:2053/files/15-20/theme3/test%20Photo.jpg">test Photo</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this was just a cut & paste error, but I'm going to state the obvious just in case. Your path to jquery has spaces in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery    /1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To be 100% doubleplus sure that jquery is loaded, open up the Firebug console and run this snippet:

```
$().jquery;
```

It should respond by printing the version number.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your document.ready function isn't enclosing all of your selector statements. You also might be missing the closing script tag.

Try adding this to the end of your script:

```
    });
</script>
```

Full script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

/* This is basic - uses default settings */

$(".image").fancybox();

/* Using custom settings */

$(".iframe").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': false
});


$("a[href$=.jpg],a[href$=.png],a[href$=.gif]").fancybox();

$(".youtube").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding': 0,
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'title': this.title,
        'width': 680,
        'height': 495,
        'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type': 'swf',
        'swf': {
            'wmode': 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen': 'true'
        }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change the src to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
```

instead of what you have here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
```

read carefully to note the difference in the src attribute of the two samples,
make this change to all the src attributes and you should be good to go.